# Cannot comment on a question or answer

Tags: bug, ios-app

I cannot comment on the post ["Harm in Nature vs. Nurture Debate"](//hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5340/harm-of-nature-vs-nurture-debate).

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug in the app. Since you don't have 50 reputation points on the site ([History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)), you cannot comment on posts (other than your own questions and answers).

Comment: Yes, I realize this is the "rule", however I have been able to do this on other Stack Exchange sites.  Does this vary from site to site?  I am still new to Stack Exchange.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the privilege thresholds, as stated in the [Help Center](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), are mostly uniform on Stack Exchange sites. (Admittedly, the Help Center isn't accessible from the iOS app.) Beta sites and Meta.SE might have different thresholds.

Comment: If you earn at least 200 points on a single site, then you can earn a [+100 association bonus](/q/141648) on all your linked accounts, which is an easy way to be allowed to comment on any site.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out online.  It was in Science Fiction & Fantasy where I currently have 31, but had < 5 when I posted the comment.